# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Request Local JavaScript vs Browser Plugin

Tags: cors, httprequest, httpresponse

I am having issue with making HTTP request from a local React application to a web server. I am getting the

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/crumbIssuer/api/json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.
```

I understand that on the server side if I set the response with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will resolve this issue. But my question is, how come a local React application is getting the CORS error, where as a browser plugin (ex. [RESTED](https://github.com/RESTEDClient/RESTED)), which is also an React application also making HTTP request with same configuration does not?

Comment: Basically, because the browser plugin is executing in the context of the browser application itself, not in the context of a web page loaded in the browser.  The browser enforces the Same Origin Policy on webpages, but any given application is not expected to enforce it.

Comment: it does in a sense, but also brings up a lot more questions, but i guess i'll jump in the rabbit hole and see, thank you!